# What does a red battery icon indicate?

Tags: battery, charging, notification-icons

While charging my Jellybean 4.1 device at my PCs' USB, I see the following red battery icon in the notification bar:

[image: badbattery]

What does the red color indicate?

Comment: are you using the original cable / charger?

Answer (score 6):

It was a hot battery alert, so the charging was interrupted for safety reasons:

[image: Overheat]